# How to get list item and display in textbox via js?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a SP list with one row for system variables, counter, etc.

I have a textfield and button on a page. When I press the button I want to:

1. get a counter value from the system list
2. display value in textbox
3. increment counter value in system list

Can’t figure out the javascript/jquery/jsom/? to perform this. Examples online are for considerably more complex scenarios.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: "counter"? As in how many items in the list? Or a value from a select list item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example for your reference.

1.Create a custom list "System List".

2.Add number field "counter" to the custom list.

3.Add the code below into a script editor web part in list page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listName="System List";
var itemId=1;
$(function(){
    $("#CounterBtn").click(function(){
        GetCounter();
    });
});
function GetCounter(){  
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "GET",               
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var counter=data.d.counter;
            $("#MyCounter").val(counter);
            UpdateCounter(counter);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}

function UpdateCounter(counter){     
    var item = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.System_x0020_ListListItem" },
        "counter": counter+1
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items("+itemId+")",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //alert('Success');            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}   
</script>
<input id="MyCounter" type="textbox"/><input id="CounterBtn" type="button" value="Get Counter"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a count of items in a list you can use AJAX for a REST API call:

```
http://yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')?$Select=ItemCount
```

For the value of a select item:

```
http://yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')?$filter=id eq 1&$select=YourCounterColumnName
```

If using jQuery, the AJAX call might look like:

```
$.ajax(
{
    "url": "/sites/yourSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')?$filter=id eq 1&$select=YourCounterColumnName",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    "success" : yourSuccessFunction,
    "error" : yourErrorFunction
}
);
```